# MapKit Xcode programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

when i write this method :

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *view =[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

    if (view == nil) {
        view =[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    }
}
```

there is warning on my `*view` object.."Incompatible pointer types initialising `MKPinAnnotationView *` with an expression of type `MKAnnotationView *` "

what is the solution for this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that you'll get a correct type of annotation using dequeue, than you can cast types simply like this:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];
```

The point is that `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` returns `id` type which can be a pointer to any object. So the compiler warns you that types `MKPinAnnotationView *` and `id` might be incompatible.

Comment: `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` is not deprecated.  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is for `UITableViewCell` objects and has _nothing_ to do with `MKAnnotationView`.  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is not deprecated either and the new `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method serves a slightly different purpose than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Comment: How could I miss that? And especially how could I mix annotations and cells? Thank you very much! :) I'll remove it from the answer to avoid confusion.